# Can we comment out [code-comments] about [commenting] on [comments]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I was creating a question a few days ago, and I noticed that there were three very similar tags: [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments), [code-comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-comments) and [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commenting).

It looks like the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments) tag has by far the most questions, while [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commenting) has the second most and [code-comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-comments) has the least.

This is what I've got:

- [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments) is only about comments within the code, and no other kind of comment, so making a whole separate tag for code-specific comments seems pointless
- [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commenting) has no tag wiki, making users tag their posts with it in the same way that they would use [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments)
- Most of the questions tagged with [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commenting) are about in-code comments, which is exactly what the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments) tag is for

Additionally, even if these tags are used for slightly different purposes, I would argue that they are much too similar to each other to each have their own tag.

Comment: You say "Most of the questions tagged with [tag:commenting] are about in-code comments…". Given that the minority of questions tagged with [tag:commenting] are not about in-code comments, what are they about?

Comment: @makyen probably comments in the same notion of this comment.. a bit of text written under a blog post or whatever. Comments in code are a one way conversation between the developer and a future developer (or themselves!), comments out of code are probably part of some slow going chat that is more two way

Comment: @Makyen I just said majority to be safe. There are 239 questions with this tag, so I'm judging this based on the fact that I looked at 40 of them and they were ALL about in code comments. My best guess is the ones that weren't about that were either closed as off-topic or soon will have the tags removed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’ve merged both [commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commenting) and [code-comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-comments) into [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/comments).

Merging creates a synonym then replaces the old source tag with the target tag on any posts that not already have the target tag, removes the source tag from posts that were tagged with both, and adjusts users’ tag favourites, ignores and tracking settings.

Thanks for proposing this!